# Unable to fit dates on x-axis

Tags: r, plot

My series includes 755 values.
I am trying to plot dates on the x-axis by using axis and a sequence to define the ticks. But the problem is that labels is not equal in length as H2S.time, so the axis is not plotted. How can I plot the dates on the axis in a fashionable manner?
The Series H2S.time includes 755 dates from 2/10/2011 to 3/5/2013 stored as strings.

```
#Import H2S Series
H2S.time<-read.table("H2S-time.txt")[1:755,1]
H2S.ts<-read.table("H2S.txt")[1:755,1]
H2S.time <- as.Date(H2S.time, format="%m/%d/%Y") 
plot(H2S.ts,col="blue",xlab="Day",)
axis(side=1, at=seq(1,755,by=20), labels=strftime(H2S.time, format="%d-%m-%Y"),cex.axis=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take subset of your labels:

```
plot(H2S.ts,col="blue",xlab="Day",xaxt='n') #no x-axis
axis(side=1, at=seq(1,755,by=20), labels=strftime(H2S.time, 
    format="%d-%m-%Y")[seq(1,755,by=20)],cex.axis=0.8)
```

Comment: Hmm...this axis only seems to add onto the other one. Is there a way I can skip plotting the other x-axis1?

Answer (score 1):

The `axis()` function is not generic, but there are special alternative functions
for plotting time related data. The functions `axis.Date()` and
`axis.POSIXct()` take an object containing dates and produce an axis with
appropriate labels. Here two example adapted from the help of the corresponding functions :

[image]

```
## example with axis.Date
layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))
random.dates <- as.Date("2001/1/1") + 70*sort(stats::runif(100))
plot(random.dates, 1:100, xaxt="n",main='pretty axes dates')
axis.Date(1, at=seq(as.Date("2001/1/1"), max(random.dates)+6, "weeks"))
### example with axis.POSIXct
with(beaver1, {
  time <- strptime(paste(1990, day, time %/% 100, time %% 100),
                   "%Y %j %H %M")
  # now label every hour on the time axis
  plot(time, temp, type="l", xaxt="n",main='pretty axes times')
  r <- as.POSIXct(round(range(time), "hours"))
  axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(r[1], r[2], by="hour"), format="%H:%M")
})
```